# Finding a preimage that is not a open set

Tags: calculus

Let 
$f\colon X=\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}=Y$

Let $f(x)=0 $ if $ x \le 0$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x>0$.

Find a $W\subset Y$ such that $W$ is open but $f^{-1}(W)$ is not open.

This is my attempt to solve the problem.

Let $W=(-1,\frac{3}{2}$) hence $W$ is open.
So then

$f^{(-1)}(W)= \{x \in X\colon f(x)\in(-1,3/2)\}$

$= \{x\in X\colon -1<f(x)<3/2\}$

$f(x)=0$

So then {$x\in \mathbb{R}\colon x\le 0\}$

Thus we get $(\infty,0]$
and it not an open set.

Is this correct?

Comment: I do not see any question.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a verification of his proof.

Comment: Yes I am wondering, If I did it right

Comment: You didn't do it right. $f^{-1}(w) = \mathbb{R}$, because $0 \in w$ and $1\in w$.

Comment: I am a confused.

Comment: Where did g(x) come from.  Also $f^{-1}(w) = \mathbb R$ which is open.

Comment: If $W$ contains any $x>0$ then $f^{-1}(W)$ will contain $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @fleablood Wherever $g$ came from, I sent it back there. Typo, I assumed.

Comment: $f(x) = 0 \in w$ and $f(x) = 1 \in w$, so $f^{-1}(w) = \mathbb R$.

Comment: I think I get it. The since the image is exactly zero and 1, then the preimage is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: I cannot decide, whose response is the best answer. Regardless I feel by asking this question, my understanding has improved considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W = (-1, \frac 1 2)$ or $W = $ any open set with $0\in W$ but $1\notin W$, then $f^{-1}(W) = (-\infty,0]$, which is not open.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.

if $y \ne 0, 1$ then $f^{-1}(y)$ is undefined and $f^{-1}({y}) = \emptyset$.

if $y = 0$ the $f^{-1}(y)$ can be any number less than or equal to 0.   $f^{-1}({y}) =  (-\infty, 0]$ (which is closed).

if $y = 1$ the $f^{-1}(y)$ can be any number less than or greater than 0.   $f^{-1}({y}) = (0, \infty)$ (which is open).

So the only option for a preimeage that is not open is  $(-\infty, 0]$.  So we must find an open set $W$ such that $0 \in W$ and $1 \notin W$.  Then $f^{-1}(W) =  (-\infty, 0]$.

We have many possibilities.

====

Another way of looking at it:

Let $W$ be an open set.  There are four possibilities.

Case 1; $W$ does not contain 0 nor 1.  As $f(\mathbb R) = \{0,1\}$, $f^{-1}(W) = \emptyset$

Case 2: $W$ contains 0 but not 1.  As $f(\mathbb R) = \{0,1\}$ and $f^{-1}({0}) = (-\infty, 0]$ , therefore  $f^{-1}(W) = (-\infty, 0]$

Case 3: $W$ contains 1 but not 0.  As $f(\mathbb R) = \{0,1\}$ and $f^{-1}({1}) = (0, \infty)$ , therefore  $f^{-1}(W) = (0, \infty)$

Case 4: $W$ contains both 0 but not 1.  As $f(\mathbb R) = \{0,1\}$, $f^{-1}({0}) = (-\infty, 0]$ and $f^{-1}({1}) = (0, \infty)$ , therefore  $f^{-1}(W) =  (-\infty, 0] \cup (0, \infty)= \mathbb R$

The only case with a non-open pre image is case 2.

Comment: Yes I like your notation, I think using y rather than x, makes the problem simpler. Because f(x)=x is y=x

Comment: @BrianO Oops, indeed.

Comment: Hmmm.  I meant to write $f^{-1}(\{y\}) = $ rather than $f^{-1}(y)$.  Which is notation I haven't seen much but makes sense to me.  So as an aside, I wonder when the convention is to use $f^{-1}(point) = point$ when the f is 1-1, $f^{-1}(point) = set$ when f is not (or do we just say "may be any of a set").  And $f^{-1}(set) = set$.  It strikes me as abuse of the distinction between point x and set {x}.  But it's been a *long* time since I viewed this from a student's perspective and back then it may have gone over my head.  What is the convention?

Comment: I am not entirely sure of the rules because I am a begginer. However the profesor who teach my class writes $f^{-1}(set)=set$

Comment: If it were up to me to me, I'd make the convention.  f(point) = point (if f is undefined at point, then claim "undefined" and if f is an inverse of a not 1-1 function then "multiple values".  But f(set) = set (which can be empty if f is undefined on set.)  Thus f({point} = {f(point)} if f is defined at point, would be empty set if not, and f({point}) = set, if f is an inverse of a not 1-1 function.  But it's not up to me.  I probably skimmed this as a student.  I'm not an instructor now, so I wonder what the actual convention is.

Comment: I,thinking on it, agree there exist an unclarity in this topic. But thanks for yours help.

Comment: It's probably nothing to worry about.  $f^{-1}(set)$ is definitely set. I'm splitting hairs and if I threw this to a student I'd just make things dificult but...

Comment: It an abuse of notation to write $f^{-1}(y)$ when $f$ is not 1-1 (it's potentially confusing), but as long as you state that it really means $f^{-1}(\{y\})$, it's ok. $f^{-1}$ *is* a relation, if not a function, and the image of a set under a relation always makes sense. (In this case, images of sets under $f^{-1}$ are preimages under $f$.) I would not speak of "multiple values", however. I think that's a lot more confusing.

Comment: That's fair enough, but it also seems an abuse of concept to refer to $f^{-1)(y)$ sometimes as an inverse function in the assumption that f is 1-1 or we are restricting it to a region where there is only one value, and other times as a relation preimage. (As you say, it is confusing, as well as inaccurate.)  It seems pretty abusive to refer to $f^{-1}(y)$ where y is a point as though it were a function rather than a relation, yet I see this again and  again.  I was wondering what the official viewpoint for instruction was.